# Typescript errors not showing up in VSCode, with Vue 3 and Volar

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to use Typescript in Vue 3, in VSCode.

When I was using the Vetur plugin, it had error highlighting, but it was overly enthusiastic - and the official Vue 3 docs recommend against it.

[image: Code with Vetur]

Then I followed the instructions on the Vue 3 docs, disabled Vetur, and enabled Volar...

But now it doesn't show *any* errors, even when things are obviously wrong.

[image: Code with Volar]

What am I missing?

My tsconfig.json is laid out exactly as is generated with the `npm create vue@3` command:

```json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.config.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's the `tsconfig.app.json` - once again, the same as generated with the `npm create vue@3` command.

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my enabled extensions in VSCode. I've done "takeover mode" as recommended in the docs, but note that even without doing takeover mode my typescript still doesn't highlight errors properly.

[image]
[image]

Is there a configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Check if you have that plugin enabled as a formatter/linter for your Vue files. This is the only thing that could be missing.

Comment: The "Vue VScode Snippets" are only for Vue2 AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

It appears that "Vue VSCode Snippets" added Vue 3 support in version 2.0.0.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/sdras.vue-vscode-snippets/changelog

I went ahead and disabled the extension just in case, but it didn't improve the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was stuck on an older version of VSCode - auto-update had stopped working.  I noticed this when I tried to use LiveShare and the GitHub integration insisted I upgrade.

I downloaded a new version of VSCode and Volar is now working.

Comment: Will do!  It says I need to wait until tomorrow :(